# Are there any web sites that store deleted questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, screen-scraping

Are there any websites (not associated with the owners, of course!) that store and/or keep track of deleted questions and/or answers, like Deletionpedia does to Wikipedia, and YouTomb does to YouTube?

Comment: This post seems related: [Building an archive of deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122249).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you -really- want to see the deleted content? Let me tell you...99% of it is garbage.

Comment: Maybe he wants to see what the SuperUser fuss is all about.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you could mine the data dump if you are that interested.  If the data is visible to 10K plus users, it should be available in the dump.

Comment: Good suggestion but ... I know that with Wikipedia, deleted pages (apart from oversighted material) are visible to admins, but they aren't in the publicly accessible dumps. I'd have thought the same would be the case with Stack Overflow.

Comment: That is very possible.  Jeff points out in the June 4th blog that only data 'that is visible on the public website' is available in the dump.  I guess it depends on what your definition of 'is' is.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted questions and answers are visible to users with at least 10k reputation points (and moderators)

Comment: That doesn't help people with a reputation of less than 10K.