# Any way to ask about the objective existence of a library/tool for a specialized programming task?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions

I had a question about a specific programming task I was trying to accomplish and attempted to ask a question about whether there existed a library/tool/framework to accomplish it, after previously searching Google and StackOverflow attempting to find one without luck:

[Grammatical inference of regular expressions for given finite list of representative strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512918/library-for-grammatical-inference-of-regular-expressions-for-given-finite-list-o)

(Note, this was worded differently originally, and perhaps less well, I've attempted to improve the title since then and am open to suggestions to improving it further if necessary.)

This was closed, and after reading some meta questions, like the following, about similar situations I have some understanding of why:

[Should there be a place to ask about programming libraries and technologies?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164400/should-there-be-a-place-to-ask-about-programming-libraries-and-technologies)

[Can I no longer ask about what technology exists?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143658/can-i-no-longer-ask-about-what-technology-exists)

Basically, it seems like the argument is that this kind of question leads to a shopping list of subjective answers and/or that they betray a lack of research attempt by the asker, although I did try to research and my intention was merely to ask whether something existed at all (which was not easy to ascertain), not to invite subjective discussion about relative merits, so I'm not sure those arguments apply in this case.

So is there no place on the SE network that I can ask an objective question about the existence of a library/tool for a programming task where that existence is not easily discoverable otherwise?

In any case, as you might have seen from my linked question, after much searching I did luck upon finding two libraries that fit my criteria, after chasing after various search terms (note that neither library is easy to find with Google even after knowing exactly what terms are appropriate: just try...:D).

Also, I note that (after figuring out that "grammatical inference" was something I should search for), I found that this question had come up at least once before at [Grammar inference library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958483/grammar-inference-library) and received no satisfactory answers (the OP asked for a *grammatical inference library* and received links to *parser generators* instead). In addition, searching for "grammar inference library" yields the previous SO question as the top link and links to the unavailable library mentioned by the previous asker as the next links; the two libraries I found are nowhere to be found. Furthermore, the original asker of the question was still interested in an answer **six months** after asking it, so obviously this is not a trivial thing to look for.

So, for the sake of anyone else facing a similar task as I had, I think the question has value and would hope to get it reopened so I can provide my own answer to it properly: is there any way I can reword or improve the question to do so, to avoid it seeming like a "shopping list" question, and/or have it moved to a more appropriate SE site?

**EDIT:** Ok, this is a bit frustrating that I have to ask myself rather than anyone being willing to offer any suggestions, but suppose the question were "Is it possible to do X with any language?" rather than "Is there a library that can do X for any language" and the answer to the previous happened to be "Yes, with library Y" (or even, within some realm of possibility, although strenuous in this case), "Yes, it's a built-in feature of language Z"? Would that make a difference, and why?

**FINAL NOTE:** For anyone needing help in a similar situation in the future, the **TL;DR** version of the solution is *avoid using the word library*.

Comment: I'm not aware of any good way to reword a shopping list question. That's like trying to make an actual shopping list not look like a list...

Comment: @animuson well, ok, but if you search for "grammar inference library" the highest search on Google is a link to the previous (unaswered) question on SO about this, so I'm merely trying to ascertain if there's any good way to help anyone else with this same question, since it seems hard to find an answer for otherwise.

Comment: (the other links top links are to a library that the OP of the other question looked into and could not find available to download)

Comment: "It should be allowed because finding an answer otherwise is hard" is not a viable argument.

Comment: @Juhana what's the argument against it then? there's nothing subjective about the question, and it has a factual answer. I only mention that because the previous arguments **against** asking whether a library existed talk about a lack of prior research by the asker.

Comment: It doesn't have *one* factual answer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad

Comment: @Juhana the question is "does this exist?": **that** has exactly one factual answer; there's no list being solicited here. you're jumping to conclusions and throwing the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: @animuson Please address my update and whether an alternate wording would still qualify as a "shopping list" in your mind. Keep in mind, the original question was **not** asking for a list, but merely whether something existed; any presumption that such a list was being solicited seems to only be prejudice judgement.

Comment: You don't explicitly have to ask for a list for your question to invite one. It's not so much about the questions you ask as it is about the answers youre likely to get.

Comment: @Bart so you can't ask a factual question on the off chance more than two people would answer it but add more information in a different way? (i.e. "**Yes**, with `Foo` vs. "**Yes**, with `Bar`)? Doesn't that exclude pretty much *any* question?

Comment: You can't ask recommendation questions, no. Which is essentially what library/tool questions are. If your practical programming problem turns out to have two different solutions, great.

Comment: @Bart again, there is no recommendation or opinion being solicited. as per my edit, this is a practical programming problem that happens to have a solution involving a library (but didn't necessarily have to, that just seemed like the most logical possible solution so I mentioned it upfront): do I need to reword the question to make that clearer?

Comment: @StephenLin Don't ask for existing tools or libraries. If you can phrase it like a practical programming problem (i.e. this is what I want to do, this is what I have, this is where I'm stuck) then you might have a perfectly valid question. And guess what; the answer to your question might well be a library recommendation. But focus on the practical problem to solve.

Comment: @Bart thank you, so to be clear, if I reword the question in that way, you would vote to reopen? after all, the purpose of this meta question was to solicit suggestions of this kind. and to be clear, the original question did state **exactly** what I had and **exactly** what I needed...

Comment: @Bart and you're honestly saying I need to jump through hoops to avoid the suggestion that there might be an existing library to do something, and just hope that someone answers with a solution that may or may not involve one? I am sorry if I sound sarcastic, but it seems odd to *avoid saying the word library* just for appearances sake....

Comment: @StephenLin That the solution might be simple does not mean that the outcome would not be entirely different. Experience tells us that recommendation questions tend to attract lists of answers. And that a large portion of those answers will be of dubious quality. And that's what we're trying to prevent from happening. A reformulation, though minor, might result in a constructive question which will attract entirely different answers of a higher quality. That is the concern here. If you manage to make it a question which by no means deserves to be closed, it stands a chance of being reopened.

Comment: @Bart this is baby out with the bathwater territory, clearly, but fine. can you take a look at the question now and let me know what you think? please kindly vote to reopen if that's ok.

Comment: @animuson thank you for having an open mind, by the way >_>

Comment: Changing to "preferably with a reference implementation" doesn't really make it *not* a list question, it just says "hey, I'm OK if you just point me to a recommendation".  You may be ok with it, but we are not.  That said, I just deleted two answers on it which were recommendation answers (as they are not answers).

Comment: To your previous point about "the question is 'does this exist?'" being an answerable question, it is, but that doesn't mean it's an answerable question we want *on this site.*  That said, the answer to your question is yes or no, and we could put that there, but that's not really *of value*.  The only things of value to this question are references/lists, and we've already determined a long time ago that this is not a good fit for the site.

Comment: **Note:** Once you've provided your self-answer, you should also flag the duplicate question for closure (even though it's older, because yours will have the better answer).

Comment: @casperOne the answer to the updated question is **Yes, what you need is a "DFA learning algorithm"**, which one of your delete answers (mine) provided. Instead of deleting it, you could have commented on it and suggested to improve it, by describing i more detail what a "DFA learning algorithm" was

Comment: @casperOne furthermore, this is no different than asking for, say, a sorting algorithm or a data structure, both of which are factual, objective questions

Comment: @StephenLin Or, what you could have done in the first place, was provide a complete answer.  You literally have forever before you submit an answer.  If you can elaborate on it, then there's no reason to not do that before you submit the answer.  Also, it is barely more than a link only answer, and we don't accept those here.

Comment: @casperOne so I'll elaborate or (if an expert comes along) they can and I'll accept that answer, the point is to have an answer there that at least defines **DFA learning algorithm** and provides **objective names of such algorithms** so others know not to go on the same search engine goose chase I did. I won't be able to elaborate further until I learn more about the algorithms and use them, after which I'll be happy to provide (factual) descriptions as best I can.

Comment: @casperOne it's also silly to delete an answer when I've already made this meta and am soliciting suggestions on how to improve the answer **for others' benefit** that I was forced to find myself **to a question that's been asked and been misunderstood/unanswered before**.

Comment: @casperOne conveniently, there's also no way to find out if other people have been trying to ask the same question either in the meantime but have been discouraged from doing so by over-zealous moderation, so who knows who my answer might help, even if I haven't been able to write an academic treatise yet?

Comment: @StephenLin No, it's not silly to delete the answer.  *It's not an answer.*  You're free to improve upon it and then flag it for undeletion when you feel that you've expanded upon it fully.  Just bringing it up on meta doesn't grant it automatic undelete status.

Comment: @StephenLin As for your very last comment.  Hyperbole much?  I dare say your definition of "over-zealous" might not mean what you think it means.

Comment: @casperOne again, the answer was **Yes, this exists, and it's called a DFA learning algorithm**, which, given prior evidence, is a non-trivial answer. So is someone asked about a sorting algorithm for a particular task, no one can answer with a name of a sorting algorithm and a link to a fuller description without fully describing it themselves?

Comment: @StephenLin BTW, you *probably* shouldn't add another answer, you should really edit the original and then flag for undeletion.  I've done that for you here, but the workflow is easier for everyone involved (and you've gotten that reputation back).

Comment: @casperOne I can't, it says it was deleted by moderation so I can't flag to undelete it >_>

Comment: @casperOne I don't know what the hyperbole is, do you mean that you don't believe it's possible anyone else is looking for the same answer and that you think it's not within the realm of possibility that the (partial) answer I've provided would be helpful to such a person in the meantime, or do you mean to say that you don't believe that SO moderation policies make it difficult to find answers to question like this even when they are **not** shopping list questions and lead to discouraging/unhelpful responses instead of suggestions to improve? (mainly *avoiding the word library*?)

Comment: @casperOne not that I'm trying to not make a value judgement here, if literally what needs to be done in situations like this is *avoid using the word library*, because that's necessary to avoid a slippery slope to subjective debate, then people ought to know that if they're trying to ask a legitimate question, right? (Hence, this meta...) And people ought to **suggest** that as well (like gnat did eventually) rather than giving sarcastic responses?

Comment: @casperOne what I'm frustrated about it that no one seems to be honest about what the real effective policy is, since the only substantive change I have made from the original question is basically *avoiding the word library* (yes, I tacked on some details about trying various things, but that was minor and in any case someone could have suggested I do so off the bat rather than closing)

Comment: @StephenLin Sorry that you're frustrated, really, but take it from the guys who have seen *thousands of questions* that the little change can make a world of difference.  The first few answers (including your own) were proof that it was soliciting recommendations (whether you wanted it to or not).  It's based on this experience that we make these decisions.

Comment: @casperOne well, it doesn't matter to me anymore, but you should call a spade a spade if that's what it is, that's all, and the behavior of those responding on this meta question (with >10,000 reputations so should know better) was not helpful and ought to be addressed.

Comment: @casperOne I specifically asked for suggestions on rewording and it turned out to be trivial do so (and someone could have just said *avoid using the word library* honestly, if that's the effective policy).

Comment: @casperOne I would also clarify that this isn't frustrating so much as amusing, to be honest, at this point, but it would be the former if I was actually still trying to find the answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would edit your question about as follows...

**Title:**

Drop the not-constructive cliche "Library for" and replace it with something like...

- *How do I do grammatical inference of regular expressions for given finite list of representative strings?*

**Text:**

1. Keep it from the beginning up to where it slips into not-constructive cliche
   *"...it's somewhat painful to do this manually."*
2. Then, replace not-constructive cliche ("Is there any existent tool or library") with something like this:
   *How do I take an arbitrary list of strings and try to infer some minimal (for some reasonable definition of minimal) spanning set of regular expressions that can be used to generate them (i.e. infer a regular grammar from a finite set of strings from the language generated by that grammar)?*
3. After that, proceed with your text
   from *"Obviously, (depending on the definition of..."* up to *"...can be later checked by a human."*

At the end of the question, I would rewrite yet another not-constructive cliche ("anyone know if there's such a tool") with something like this:

- *Options I considered so far are: either to make a reasonable attempt at writing something to do this myself, or looking for an appropriate library.*

---

Generally, edit approach for above is based on what I learned in a [similar discussion at Programmers meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5454/31260): instead of resource / tool / book request, one would rather present an **underlying problem** - a problem that was intended to be solved with particular resource / tool / book requested.

Comment: thank you kindly for the suggestion, can you take a look at what the current edit looks like and let me know what you think?

Comment: thank you kindly for your assistance, accepted