# People who downvote all answers on a post because the question is low quality

Tags: discussion, down-votes, low-quality-posts

I'm sure this is a documented phenomenon, but I haven't been able to find a meta post about it.

Sometimes, I answer a question given in a post when I know the post is low quality (not an obvious duplicate and with a clear problem). Then, I notice -2 in my reputation drawer and see that someone downvoted the question and all votes on the page.

I was wondering:

- if this phenomenon is something that happens in general?
- if this is a sign that I should just stop answering low-quality questions?

Comment: "if this phenomenon is something that happens in general" - Yes. I see it quite often. Not on *every* bad question, but often enough to notice. "if this is a sign that I should just stop answering low-quality questions" - People who downvote correct answers to bad questions often do so to encourage just that.

Comment: @Mysticial As to the second point, is it just in general a bad idea to answer --- and I don't mean for myself but for the site.

Comment: Downvoting good answers to bad questions remains a highly controversial topic. The SE staff seems to discourage it. But there are countless users who do it anyway in an apparent desperate attempt to attack the question quality problem.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions

Comment: No one can stop you from answering bad questions before they are closed. But do realize that you do so at the risk of getting downvotes as well as losing the respect of certain users. (which you may or may not care about)

Comment: @AstroCB probably even more related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601

Comment: @Mysticial It is indeed controversial, though I tend to agree with ChrisF on this one - ["I'm uncomfortable with the idea of a "good answer" to a "bad question. ... If the question it truly un-salvageable then I would have doubts as to whether any answers could be considered "good"."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237471/213963)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is common phenomenon. Often, the reason for it is to discourage users from answering bad questions. If a question is low quality, it should be hard to answer (if possible) anyway, which discourages most users.

Then, some people for further reinforcement will downvote answers to discourage the behavior. Not only does answering bad questions harm the site, by adding unnecessary data etc., but it harms the author by taking lots of time they could be using to help the community.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat what?!

Comment: Oh... wow. just wow.

Comment: Hahaha, now I have to explain to everyone why I suddenly burst out laughing. That was one of the best typos I've ever seen.

Comment: @Doorknob would've been better complete with a comma.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, some people will systematically downvote answers to poor questions, irrespective of the quality of the answers.

**However, the fact is that poor questions elicit poor answers.** It is perfectly possible for a poor question to get a bunch of answers which are all poor in their own right. The fact that all answers on a poor question have been downvoted is not sufficient proof that someone has been downvoting answers merely because of the question. The answers may be bad in and of themselves. I particularly recall a *good* regex question on SO that got a total of four answers that were all incorrect. If all answers on a good question can be incorrect, it is all the more likely on a bad question.

I often see guess answers posted on questions that underspecify the problem. A guess can be informed or it can be a shot in the dark. Sometimes there is not enough information to tell what the real issue faced by the OP is but there *is* enough information to know that some of the guess answers cannot *possibly* be the solution. Of course the answerer is baffled when the answer is downvoted but it is not proof that the downvote is due to anything else than the quality of the answer. **If you guess an answer, then unless you truly know the topic involved by the question inside and out, there's a high chance that your guess is wrong.**

There's also the case of opinion-based questions being posted in venues where opinion-based questions are not appropriate. For instance, the main SO site. (By opposition to SO's Meta, which has more tolerance for opinions.) Some think that if they merely parrot a popular opinion, surely their answer is worthy of an upvote. Voters may set the bar higher than this. As I see it, the answerer should at least support their opinion with substantial reasons supporting. ("Do X because [some known name] says you should do X" is *not* a solid reason.) An opinion that does not do this is worthy of a downvote.

My point is yes it does happen that people downvote answers due to the quality of the question, but there are cases where it *may* look like this is happening, when *in fact* it is not.

I prefer not to answer low quality question as I feel it is a waste of time. It does not mean I never answer such questions but when I do, I make sure my answer is an informed one (no shots in the dark) and I'm willing to live with the downvotes of those who cannot tolerate answers to such questions. (I did get a few.)

Comment: Answering an unclear question with a shot in the dark should give you an MS-Paperclip Office Assistant user avatar for the next week.  *(nasally voice)* "It looks like you're trying to write a business letter.  Can I help?"