# The irony of "vote to delete" VS asking people to copy link text into the answer in case the link changes

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I'm a little frustrated that content I've Favorited/bookmarked is no longer available with no redirect or context of what used to be there.

- If people who answer a question are often downvoted for not summarizing the content of an external link, shouldn't the folks who delete historic / highly voted questions (thus breaking the bookmark) need to summarize and replace it with something?

It seems to me that SO's ideology of the broken URI is one sided and inconsiderate of its own users.  The one who deletes highly referenced questions should have a 301/2 redirect or summary in place of that question.

What are your thoughts on having a system to promote good deletions and penalize bad deletions for Mods who have that power?

We penalize our own answerers whenever they don't summarize link text.  (under the assumption the remote link can be deleted or changed)... but there isn't any control to govern delete behavior to keep up with the user base.

Food for thought:

- It would be interesting to see how long it has taken 5 votes to delete a question vs how many active users there are over time.  My guess is that 5 votes is insufficient to determine community consensus as the community grew larger
- The quantity of 10k users with delete powers has grown significantly over time and therefore have a higher chance to act against community consensus or subject matter expert consensus.

Comment: How is it broken? I care if links on the site are broken, rendering the site's content useless. That should be prevented. But I don't care much about your personal bookmarks ending up broken to be honest.

Comment: *"promote good deletions and penalize bad deletions"*...you might want to state what the definition of those is, before you ask to put a system in place that judges those.

Comment: Deletions are harmful. I don't know why deleting anything that has at least a certain number of upvotes (say, 10) is allowed in the first place.

Comment: @Bart - SO.Meta won't support favoriting an answer, so the advice is to save the link.  You should care, since that is the only offically supported way... and it is affected by deletes

Comment: Oh, crap, not this _again_... <sigh>

Comment: Historic/highly voted questions are deleted because they no longer belong on the site. Link-only answers are downvoted because they have the potential to become useless, and should be deleted if they stay link-only and the link breaks. This seems pretty consistent to me.

Comment: @makerofthings7 I really don't care. If there is interesting relevant content I know I would like to refer back to, I copy it to a file. I don't rely on links external to me. And I'm still waiting for your good/bad deletions definitions.

Comment: `The quantity of MODs with delete powers has grown significantly over time and therefore have a higher chance to act against community consensus or subject matter expert consensus.` This makes _absolutely_ no sense at all. Care to clarify, please?

Comment: @YannisRizos If a mod closes / deletes a post, then no additional votes are needed.

Comment: @makerofthings7 That part we got. And Yannis certainly did. But how about *"have a higher chance to act against community consensus or subject matter expert consensus"*.

Comment: @makerofthings7 I know. But how do you go from that to `therefore have a higher chance to act against community consensus or subject matter expert consensus.`

Comment: @YannisRizos  `Not this again` .. so if people keep on complaining why isn't it seen as a problem that needs to be fixed?

Comment: @makerofthings7 People complaining doesn't necessarily mean they are right, people can complain about anything, so what? [Listen to Your Community, But Don't Let Them Tell You What to Do](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do.html)...

Comment: @Bart / Yannis - If a greater number of individuals can act unilaterally, then there is a chance those unilateral actions are not consistent with the broader thinking of the group.  That chance of inconsistency increases proportionally with the quantity of people who have this power.

Comment: @makerofthings7 And... have you noticed any inconsistency? If so, please update your question to tell us about it.

Comment: @YannisRizos Replace "MODs" with "10k users" and it makes sense.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ it makes sense how?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ I thought they were synonyms .. edited..

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ If it makes sense to you, how about you venture an answer?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124464/show-embattled-deleted-questions-to-the-public-as-if-they-were-10k-users

Comment: @Bart There's a greater number of users with delete powers, which makes it easier for otherwise acceptable questions to be deleted by a few users, acting against the wishes of the community at large.

Comment: @YannisRizos I happen to agree with the OP, so adding an answer wouldn't add much to the discussion. I *will* bring down the house on this witch hunt, but I need to do some more research to prepare a better argument.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ And we have some sort of figures/cases to back that up with? Or are we talking pure numbers here? I mean, is this a real issue or hypothetical? With the current delete rules, deletion should become increasingly difficult, the more popular a question is. So I fail to see a real problem here, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Bart They ditched the popularity requirement, which IMO worked fine (ie: popular questions needed hundreds of votes to be deleted, effectively making them undeletable by regular users). Now you only need at most 10 users to delete *any* question.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Ah, thanks. I was unaware of that

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ `makes it easier for otherwise acceptable questions to be deleted by a few users` Links, or it didn't happen.

Comment: @YannisRizos The vast majority of (if not all) questions with at least 100 upvotes should never be deleted.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Why? Just because they were heavily upvoted? Is that _really_ your argument? If so, then you are talking about popular questions, not `otherwise acceptable` questions...

Comment: @YannisRizos A question shouldn't just suddenly become unacceptable because a few people have a problem with it. The hundreds of upvotes on it and its answers should be a strong indication of how the community at large feels about the question.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Oh come on, you know that's nonsense, as an SO mod you know how pointless upvotes can be, people will upvote just about anything... Just post an answer here with links to some deleted questions you feel were incorrectly deleted, and let's see how many will get undelete votes.

Comment: @YannisRizos The system is currently prejudiced towards deletion. Only after it's been deleted you can come in and complain about it. But how good is that if you can't even find the question? It should be the other way around, ie: **much** harder to delete stuff, and if it's really bad, the users who have a problem with it can post here asking for a deletion.

Comment: I really hope you realize your two complains are meaningless; the "put text in your answer" requirement is in place *exactly* because stuff gets deleted. Even if it's a link to another SO answer, if it gets deleted or changed, your answer may be useless. They're totally unrelated ideas.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ You, as a moderator, _can_ find the questions and are in a unique position to _prove_ the system doesn't work with _actual_ evidence. How about you stop wasting your time arguing in comments, and help change the system by actually showing us it doesn't work?

Comment: @YannisRizos That's `[status-planned]` for me, but while I wait I will support the position in any way possible - including arguing in comments. It's not a waste of time, it helps raise awareness to the problem.

Comment: @YannisRizos I think the deletion of popular questions is *easily* the most controversial issue on SE. It's been a point of attrition, causing grief for as long as I can remember. Arguments for and against it have been hashed and rehashed *ad nauseum*. You can't expect me to come up with something new, substantiated, and viable overnight.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Not overnight, certainly. But as you say this isn't a new issue, and you seem to feel very strongly about it and for quite some time. In any case, I'll be more than happy to discuss your arguments and review your evidence whenever you choose to present them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I disagree.

First, it takes **3 votes *minimum*** to delete a question. More if the question is popular (Popularity = (total score of question + all answers) / 20).

If question is deleted, it can be **undeleted** by powerful users, in the same manner.

If a specific question you had bookmarked was broken, and now shows a 404 page to you, post it here on meta under a [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) tag, and bring it to our awareness. If we feel the same, the question will be undeleted.

I don't feel that there's such a way as "bad" deletions, as much as there are "wrongful" ones. In which case, bringing it to the collective awareness of the community is the correct course of action.

Alternatively, work hard, get the 10k privilege **cast delete/undelete** votes, to trigger the change yourself, or possible flag a deleted question for undeletion if you think a diamond's intervention is appropriate.

Deletions usually happen for very low-quality cases. So I doubt it happens spontaneously.

Comment: They more or less ditched the popularity requirement, which IMO worked fine (ie: popular questions needed hundreds of votes to be deleted, effectively making them undeletable by regular users). Now you only need at most 10 users to delete *any* question.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ: The algorithm may need to be tweaked to compensate the increase of 10k+ users. But I think the current system fundamentally works fine.

Comment: 'Deletions usually happen for very low-quality cases.' That is *profoundly* untrue these days. And how much is the ability to undelete a question worth when you can't find it unless you have the exact URL?

Comment: @Pekka: Good points. Maybe a 10k review queue?

Comment: 10K+ users already have access to a list of recent deletions. That said, it's a limited list and it isn't that really helpful, a [delete/undelete queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148204/can-we-get-some-more-review-queues-questions-with-delete-votes-recently-close) would be awesome. /cc: @Pekka

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ - Do you have the link to them ditching the popularity requirement?

Comment: @jmort253 I don't, but just look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/394601/revisions). It's got 1000+ upvotes between the question and the highest voted answer, which would require 50+ votes to delete, right there. Yet it was deleted by 10 users.

Comment: @jmort253 'Twas earlier this year, in the great deletionist wars, when the complaints about moderator deletions became a daily lament on MSO, when Shog or Jeff (don't remember exactly, I think it was Shog already) capped the maximal number of necessary delete votes so the community stood a chance of deleting what they deemed delete-worthy without having to beseech a moderator because a myriad of old-time users liked boat-programming in the mists of past.

Comment: @NullUserException_: [Followup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153607/were-the-popularity-rules-of-a-question-changed)

Comment: @DanielFischer - That can't really be Jeff. Someone hacked into his account and posted that as him. ;)  These examples just aren't on-topic. I guess if there's stuff that shouldn't be deleted, it should just be locked like the [Cartoon Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) (which would clearly get a delete vote from me if I could...)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ The number was capped some time after [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity), I don't remember whether Jeff went when March came or April.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ - [February 29th, 2012](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121595/thank-you-jeff-atwood/124020#124020). It's easy to remember because it was leap day.

Comment: The exclusionists have clearly won; undeletion is very  rarely possible except for exceptional posts.