# Were the "popularity" rules to delete a question changed?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete, rules

I've read **[the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/166899)**<sup>[1]</sup> regarding the rules of deletion, and specifically "popularity".

> The new rules:
>
> - 10k rep users get **5** deletion votes per day on questions they don't own - [deletion rules on questions one does own are still in
>     effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/166899)
> - popular questions require more deletion votes to be deleted, at a ratio of 20:1 - a question's popularity is defined by the sum of its
>     score plus all its answers' scores. For example, a question with score
>     20 will require 4 deletion votes (3 base votes + 1 popularity vote).

However, when I look at **[this revision log](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/394601/revisions)**, I see that the question was deleted by 10 people, despite it having **over 1000 points between the question and the top answer alone**.

Have the rules changed? Is there a maximum user count?

Could we get clarification?

<sub>[1] Note: This answer is linked at the relevant [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) page!</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Reputation and Historical Archives](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/):

> **Third**, it should be easier for the community to both delete AND undelete most questions. Previously, it could take hundreds of votes to remove some of these extremely popular questions – that sounds good, but in practice it just meant folks gave up voting and asked moderators to delete for them. Creating more grief for moderators and less democracy was never the intention – from here on out, it will take at least three and at most 10 votes to delete even the most popular questions, and an equivalent number to undelete them.

The change was in response to about a week of ugliness on Meta Stack Overflow, that started when people started noticing their reputation decreasing, due to the [recent changes in the reputation system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes), and ended (?) with the [Community-led deletionism: a protocol for sanity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity) discussion.

Comment: This should be part of the [meta-tag:faq].

Comment: @Madara, [it is...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) or you literally just put it there :-).

Comment: @Ben: **Now** it is, after I put it there (look at the revisions) :)