# What is the best SO mirror to view deleted questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Building an archive of deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122249/building-an-archive-of-deleted-questions)

Sometimes I meet questions ([recent one](http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions/679/621.html), also about gitignores, or about computers in sailing) for which I feel "Page not found" even by looking at the link: "such funny question can't thrive on SO no matter how useful they are". Not all deleted questions are equally useless, so I google the title and find it mirrored somewhere.

Is there some official or the most popular mirror (compare to [DeletionPedia](http://deletionpedia.dbatley.com) for Wikipedia) where [deleted] questions gets (and ideally continues evolving)?

Comment: Here's a mirror that occasionally saves deleted questions: 9nit.com. For example: http://www.9nit.com/search/?keywords=css+gotchas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't official mirror as Stack Exchange doesn't want to just work around their own system

I found that [Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com/deleted) is an useful one