# Official Archive/Museum for the closing sites

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Building an archive of deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122249/building-an-archive-of-deleted-questions)

There are two purposes an archive is needed: The closure of beta sites, and the deletion of old yet popular questions on Stackoverflow (and SuperUser and Serverfault if applicable).

One of the main purpose of StackExchange is to improve the web, by allowing great quality questions and answers to be written. One of the worst crimes of a website is to break links, that crime gets worse with the popularity of the content, and there is no denying that StackExchange is popular. The deletion of old questions on SO, and the closing of SE sites is sad, but understandably correct.

So move the questions to a readonly site called something like archive.stackexchange.com.

Pros:

- Links remain intact, the old links can be forwarded to the new site
- Much less loss of data/content
- All the old and now considered off topic can be removed from SO without any issues/controversy at all.

Cons:

- Cost, even though readonly the site would still need to be run (obviously)*
- Somewhat contrary to the idea of SE sites which is to create communities of experts, although it helps maintainer the great SE community (and the web in general)

*though I believe that deleted questions are still available to 10k users? So they are still being stored and accessed?

To reduce clutter, the questions available from closed sites should only be archived if they have an answer, and with maybe at least one vote on either the question or answer, or if there is more than a certain number of views

Comment: And heap big heap more dupes: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Archive+deleted

Comment: for the site name, I'd rather prefer **museum.stackexchange.com**

Comment: The reason I started a new question was because what I'm suggesting covers both the old popular deleted questions and the closed sites. Although there are data dumps of those site, the purpose of stackexchange is to make quality questions and answers easily accessible, a data dump is far from accessible it can be considered non exisistant for the general users. Also I'm not suggesting every deleted question is archived only those that are useful based on their views, number of answers and votes.

Comment: Already stack exchange has a lot of sites and many people are not familiar with them, hence I feel it makes no point in creating a new website for posting old content.

Comment: Not posting old content simply moving it off the existing site to declutter them while not loosing the data people have put the time and effort in to create properly

Comment: Quite a bit has changed since February when the duplicate was asked. More sites have been closed and Jeff has left stackexchange (I think?). that question has an answer marked as accepted, but nothing has been done. If popular (when I say popular I mean views, answers and votes not popular subject) questions are now considered deletable, what's to stop questions consider acceptable now from being deleted in the future? The whole thing is against the appare values of stackexchange, the community being in control of the questions, like free access to them.

Comment: @Jonathan [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046) (ignore the "my" part and substitute it with "someone else's, with which I agree")

Comment: @The Establishment I can't edit someone else's questions

Comment: Yes you can. Click the "edit" link and suggest an edit. If it improves the question, it will be improved. Sure, you can't change the meaning, but that doesn't seem like an issue in this case. Also, the advice about setting bounties is particularly relevant. You can say anything you want in the bounty message.

Comment: @TheEstablishment, ok but it would somewhat change the question, also I can't add a bounty as there is already one in place. Also the people with the power to do anything have little interest in a bounty, what value is 500 rep to someone with 10K+ and a moderator?

Comment: Also that question is about a "fan" site, not an official one, I'm suggesting an official site, which would require little effort to set up (given how many sites the SE team have created from Area 51), and would be redirected to by the existing and imminently broken links