# Archive with deleted questions for users with less than 10K rep?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Building an archive of deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122249/building-an-archive-of-deleted-questions)

As someone who is trying to learn how to master Emacs, I found the question **'The single most useful Emacs feature'**  a great source of information before it was deleted. I noticed that this question isn't listed under the [Popular deleted questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73455/popular-deleted-questions-list).

I think I have read here in Meta that the Team may be working on building a static archive of these questions and/or potentially freezing them with a locking mechanism.

With this, my questions are:

1. Is there a reason why the Emacs question was not added to the [Popular deleted questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73455/popular-deleted-questions-list)?
2. Has there been any progress on setting up an archive of snapshots of deleted questions?
3. Is there **any** way a user with less than 10K could retrieve the contents of a question like the one I mentioned?

Comment: http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=60367&service=stackoverflow

Comment: Do you have a link to the question anywhere?

Comment: The popular deleted questions list (and other posts like it) are not official. It doesn't have a maintenance team. New items get added whenever the heck someone remembers that it exists and feels like adding a deleted post.

Comment: see also: [Building an archive of deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122249/165773)