# Create a "Best of Stack Overflow" section on Meta

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, archive

Yesterday, I was browsing some awesome sites that resemble http://meta.stackoverflow.com, you know the likes of 4chan, Reddit and Craigslist. I was mysteriously guided to a place called "best of xxx" (substitute xxx with the site name). Then a really great idea hit me: why don't we have a section called "Best of Stack Overflow" in which we can move all those entertaining questions some people worked so hard for instead of binning them permanently? Surely the effort of making those questions fun to read deserve some recognition?

Comment: such questions are just trash and offtopic. we don't need them here.

Comment: [Strongly related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122249/building-an-archive-of-deleted-questions) - but that is a little old, so I'm not using a single binding vote to close this (and, Shog had some ideas that never really got explored).

Comment: Such a section would actually be called "worst of" I think.

Comment: It is an archive of "entertaining" questions that's sought after ... not just all deleted one.

Comment: When people guide *me* to places called "best of xxx", there's usually no substitution going on...

Answer (score 6):

We already have those. It is called [**hot**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot), [**week**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=week) and [**month**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=month).

There you can visit the hottest questions this day, this week and this month.

If you want to see the most voted questions ever then you can go to the [**questions**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) tab.

Comment: "all those entertaining questions" - I think the OP here meant things like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/447356) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9033/447356) which were fine long ago but no longer fit Stack Overflow - those are kept for now but thousands of other similar posts with lots of upvotes and answers got indeed deleted and the OP want to preserve them, not the good on topic questions we get these days.

Comment: currently "hot" is hardly "best"; it's filled with too much garbage [because of broken hotness formula](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192046/in-network-hot-questions-formula-discard-answers-when-voting-evidence-indicat)

Answer (score 4):

This has [come up in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122249/building-an-archive-of-deleted-questions), on several sites. The idea of some kind of archive is appealing to those that want to preserve the *culture* surrounding the content, and not *just* the content itself.

The root of most concerns about it comes from the concern that it would end up detracting from the value of the main site, and it's hard to just dismiss those concerns as invalid. From broken windows to reverse broken windows to dogs and cats living together, and the issue of curating and maintaining it. To be clear, I'm not *against* the idea, but I can't really find enough benefit in it to find the requisite amount of motivation needed to actually sit down, design and build such a thing.

If such a thing is going to come into existence, *someone else is going to need to build it in a way that makes people love it enough to really care*. The idea of community choice awards encompassing a mix of not only fun stuff, but also the truly amazing stuff that is still considered on-topic is a very interesting idea.

However, I think we've come to a point where we've gone full circle several times with the idea, and nobody was really able to come up with a compelling idea for implementation that sufficiently addressed the concerns many had about it.

If this is something you *really* want to have, then my best advice is ***go for it*** using everything we make available. This keeps coming up, but ... something *much more solid* than a general idea would need to emerge for real traction to be gained.

Answer (score 1):

There are already tabs for [hot](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot), [top questions in past week](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=week) and [top questions in the past month](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month). These seem to already fill the same purpose that any "best of" page would serve.